# Hexagon button does not appear in my app

Tags: android, android-drawable

I have this hexagon button in my drawable folder

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:height="24dp"
android:width="27dp"
android:viewportHeight="28.0"
android:viewportWidth="26.0">

<path android:fillColor="#00ffffff"
    android:pathData="m723,314c-60,103.9 -120,207.8 -180,311.8 -120,0 -240,0 -360,0C123,521.8 63,417.9 3,314 63,210.1 123,106.2 183,2.2c120,0 240,0 360,0C603,106.2 663,210.1 723,314Z"
    android:strokeColor="#000000" android:strokeWidth="4"/>
```

But when I try to use it in my application it does not appear

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_normal"
    android:layout_width="241dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn_highscores"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn_highscores"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_easy"
    android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
    android:background="@drawable/hexagon"
    android:text="Normal"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
```

Comment: Could you please explain, how are you using the button in the application

Comment: its a simple button [link](https://image.prntscr.com/image/8BE0p1dVTtul9NlKSYUalA.jpeg)  where it says "normal" there should be a hexagon button but it's not there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have the wrong coordinates for the vector path.

For starters, you have points with coordinates 700+ whereas the viewport height and width is 26.

If you change your viewport to 750 * 750 you can now see the hexagon shape in the drawable file:
[image]

However, as you can see, the shape is outside the visible area of the screen (see the blue area).

As such, I would advise you to try another set of coordinates for the hexagon shape.